# Programmatically calling gcloud background functions in the Emulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, serverless

I have deployed a gcloud background function (pubsub) in emulator.

It is getting succesfully invoked from command line

```
functions call helloPubSub --data='{"message":"Hello World"}'
```

How to invoke gcloud local function from local server code ?

= = =

Below is my code on server side to publish to topic

```
pubsub
  .topic(topicName)
  .publisher()
  .publish(dataBuffer)
  .then(results => {
    const messageId = results[0];
    console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
    res.status(200)
    res.send({hello:'world'})

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
    res.status(200)
    res.send({err:err})
  });
```

I receive following error message

```
{"err":{"code":7,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}},"note":"Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) it states:

> Note: Functions deployed in the Emulator with non-HTTP triggers like Cloud Storage or Cloud Pub/Sub will not be invoked by these services. The Emulator is intended as a development environment only, so you would need to call these functions manually to have them invoked.

So if you deployed a function locally with Cloud Pub/Sub trigger, the only way to invoke it is using the command line command:

```
functions call [your-function]
```